# Display only unique values from a Matrix column

Tags: matrix, pixelandtonic

Am trying to display only unique values from a matrix column

Is it possible with using the Query module?

Answer (score 2):

Well, the query module gives you direct access to SQL querying your database tables, so this seem quite possible. It depends on the complexity: Are you looking to isolate rows based on a unique column? Isolate entirely unique rows? We'd need more details to help better.

But, without more info, a good start is learning about the `DISTINCT` clause available in MySQL queries: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-distinct.aspx

Comment: Thank you @jrothafer. I was trying to isolate rows based on a unique column value. Stash worked fine. Used stash:set_list and get_list to store values of matrix field in a list and applied the unique="yes" parameter to make it work. Tried the Query module as well and it too worked. However, will stick with stash as I am able to reuse the values from the list.